# C Program to add 2 integers produce abnormal output

Tags: c, int, printf, scanf

I've already looked all over the internet but haven't found anything related to this.

Here's the output

```sh
Enter First Number: 2
Enter Second Number: 3
Total: 6422308Press any key to continue . . .
```

*Here's the code*

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int num1;
    int num2;

    int total;

    printf("Enter First Number: ");
    scanf("%i", &num1);

    printf("Enter Second Number: ");
    scanf("%i", &num2);

    total = num1 + num2;

    printf("Total: %i", &total);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Well, I expect the output to be proper

Comment: Remove the `&` from `total`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks! it works but what's the science behind it?

Comment: `printf` is not expecting a pointer, but a variable itself to be printed. It is different from `scanf` which needs a pointer to be able to store a value into it.

Comment: The "science behind it" is that `scanf` is special (very special, and confusingly so).  When you pass variables to functions  (like passing `total` to `printf`, you normally just say the name of the variable: `printf("Total: %i", total)`.  `scanf` does need that `&`, but only because `scanf` is special.  Don't look at `scanf` and assume that the way it works is the way all functions work.

Comment: see these links example section to see proper way of using input and output in C: [scanf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), [printf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Not mentioned yet but you may want `%d` rather than `%i` in the `scanf` line.  The `%i` means it will look for leading `0` or `0x` to read octal or hexadecimal respectively. (e.g. try typing `015` instead of `15`).

Answer (score 1):

**Your Problem** The line `printf("Total: %i", &total);` should be changed to  `printf("Total: %i", total);`

**The Reason** The `&` unary operator in C gets the address of the operand(variable). Notice in the usage of `scanf` you need the '&' operator. The reason why you need it for `scanf` is because the variable needs to be modified outside of the scope of the calling function(the scope of main() in our case). On the other hand `printf` just needs the value of the variable, so just the variable name `total` is needed.

**To Clarify**
`0x6422308` is the address in memory where the variable `total` is located which is equivalent to `&total`.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently printing the memory address of total, and not what the value stored in that memory address is. This is because c utilizes pointers, allowing you to set memory addresses, access information from memory addresses, and use pointer arithmetic to sift through memory. When prefixing a variable with the `&` operator, you are essentially declaring that you want the memory address that variable is stored in. If you wanted the value of a memory address, you would have to dereference the memory address with the `*` operator. I haven't tried this, but you could do something like
`printf("Total %i",*(&total))` to dereference the memory address of total to get the value.

The above is a way too complicated for this application however, and you do not need to mess with memory addresses in printing for this case. Therefore, you can just pass the variable total to printf and everything will be good (since total is not a pointer).

Remove the `&` inside of your total printf and everything should work correctly. You can see how to use printf and scanf [here](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-printf-and-scanf/)

Answer (score 0):

`&x` stands for the address of the variable `x`. So `scanf(..., &x)` makes sense because the function `scanf` requires an address of a variable for putting data. And `printf(&x)` outputs an address of the variable `x`, instead of value of this variable. You should use `printf(x)` to obtain the expected result.